# How to copy the output from vim command line?

Tags: neovim, lunarvim

I use lunarvim. I want to get the version of the it to a file.

I read this link:
[redirect vi command output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141661/redirect-vi-command-output-to-a-file)

I tried this command:

```
:redir > vim.output | LvimVersion | redir END
```

But I get error messages:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I suspect LvimVersion not to support |. You probably have to write a function to get rid of the |.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `LvimVersion` command doesn't support the `|` operator.

A solution is to define a function:

```
function! LvimVersion()
  redir! > vim.output
  LvimVersion
  redir END
endfunction
```

You could then call the function instead:

```
:call LvimVersion()
```

You could also ask LunarVim people to add the `-bar` flag to the command definition of LvimVersion or define your own LvimVersion2 that does it.

```
command! -bar LvimVersion2 LvimVersion
```

With this second version the trick will work

```
:redir! > vim.output | LvimVersion2 | redir END
```

Comment: Hi I want to know the details of the '|' mark. 
But I type `:he |` then not get the answer I want. How to find the help file of the mark "|" here? Thank you.

Comment: You can type `:h bar` it is a way to put multiple commands in one line (or multiple script line in one line). But not every Vim command accept it because some need to consider `|` as a part of their argument (e.g. `:s`) If you want your command to support it you have to define it with the `-bar` option.